# how to correctly check if dataframe column has "False" in it

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with boolean values. If any of the values is `False`, I want to do something. I have 2 options to do so:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame(data = [{'bool': False}, {'bool': True}])

In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
    bool
0  False
1   True

In [4]: if (df['bool'] is False).any():
   ...:     print ('yay!!!!')
   ...: 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-0c98c5d85cb6> in <module>
----> 1 if (df['bool'] is False).any():
      2     print ('yay!!!!')
      3 

AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'any'

In [5]: if (df['bool'] == False).any():
   ...:     print ('yay!!!!')
   ...: 
yay!!!!
```

As you can see, the 1st (`is`) fails, and the 2nd (`==`) succeeds. However, when running pre-commit (version 1.20.0) on this, I get the following error:

```
E712 comparison to False should be 'if cond is not False:' or 'if cond:'
```

which reverts me back to the 1st solution (which doesn't work)

How can I solve this?

```
Python 3.6.12
pandas==1.1.5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test if not all values are `True`s by test `Series` by [`Series.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.all.html) and then invert scalar by `not`:

```
if not df['bool'].all():
    print ('yay!!!!')
yay!!!!
```

If want invert Series:

```
if (~df['bool']).any():
    print ('yay!!!!')
yay!!!!
```

In pandas working with `1d` (`Series`) or `2d` (`DataFrame`) data, so for test is not used `is` , which is not used for [check for identity of arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is).

Comment: I can - but can you explain why the 1st option I tried failed?

Comment: @CIsForCookies `df['bool']` is a series, therefore it is not `False`

Comment: @CIsForCookies - I think because `is` is used [check for identity of scalars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is)